# How to move nested divs containers to the left if content increases

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that has a dropdown menu and a label with a button on it.like follows

```
<div class="container ">
  <div id="User">
    <div id="BtnUser">
      <div id="dropMe">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a onclick="UserdropDownDetails()">
            <div class="triangle"></div>
          </a>
          <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content ">
            <ul>
              <span class="dropDownMenu">hello <span class="ColonGreen">:</span>&nbsp;hi</span>
              <span class="dropDownMenu Availability">Availablility <span class="ColonGreen">:</span></span>
              <span class="dropDownMenu">helloooo <span class="ColonGreen">:</span></span>

            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id=UserDetails><label>tessssttt&nbsp;tessssssssssst</label></div>
      <div id="logoutDiv"><button id="btnLogout" name="btnLogout">Log out</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g9tdcrxh/2/

The problem I am having is when the text `tessssst` grows it moves to the left which I want.but it's blocking the `triangle` dropdown. How do I get the `BtnUser` div to expand and the triangle to move left when the text grows?

This is what it's doing

[image]

I need the position of the triangle to stay where it is, only when the text grows then can it move. The logout button should also stay where it is.

I want it to grow like this

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Your guidance will be highly appreciated, can you do it in jQuery?

Comment: On both #dropMe and #UserDetails you have `display: block` and control their positions with margins. If you want dynamic resizing/placement, you have to change those properties. Try changing `display` to `inline-block`, adding `float: left`/`right` or using relative positioning and/or `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a lot of changes. If you right-click elements in your browser, you should be able to select "inspect element" and hovering them in the list that appears, you can see their sizes/margins/paddings..

```
<div class="container">
    <button id="btnLogout" name="btnLogout">Log out</button>
    <div class="user">
        <div class="userDetails">teshrthrtrthrthtrhtrhabcdefghijklteshrthrtrthrthtrhtrhabcdefghijklteshrthrtrthrthtrhtrhabcdefghijklteshrthrtrthrthtrhtrhabcdefghijkl</div>
        <div class="dropMe">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a onclick="UserdropDownDetails()">
                    <div class="triangle"></div>
                </a>
                <div class="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content ">
                    <ul>
                        <span class="dropDownMenu">hello <span class="ColonGreen">:</span>&nbsp;hi</span>
                        <span class="dropDownMenu Availability">Availablility <span class="ColonGreen">:</span></span>
                        <span class="dropDownMenu">helloooo <span class="ColonGreen">:</span></span>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

body {
    margin: 5px;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.user {
    overflow: hidden;

    margin-right: 95px;

    min-width: 500px;
    max-width: calc(100% - 100px);
    float: right;

    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .5em;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    padding-top: 0;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    box-shadow: inset 0 10px 20px #333;
}

#btnLogout {
    width: 90px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #74be43 0%,#3a953e 64%,#3a953e 64%,#0f773b 100%);
    border: 1px solid #BFE1A7;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #ECF5EC;
    border-right: 1px solid #ECF5EC;
    line-height: 20px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    right: 5px;
}

.dropMe {
    width: 10px;
    /*margin-top: -26px;*/
    /*margin-left: 110px;*/
    float:right;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.userDetails {
    /*margin-top: -20px;*/
    /*margin-left: -220px;*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #cecece;

    text-align: left;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    float:right;
    min-width: 376px; /* 600px - 110px (left margin) - 20px (arrow) - 90px (button) - 4px (button margin) */
    max-width: calc(100% - 20px); /* 20px (arrow) */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g9tdcrxh/9/

Comment: hi,the logout button disappears because its set to right:2px; so i tried to change it to left:320px so that it appears,but then with that,it stops working.if you notice in the #logoutDiv

Comment: yep i tried it on your fiddle,if you click on your fiddle,theres no logout button there,so i tried to change the position of the logoutDiv

Comment: when it reaches the button the text is going behind it,when it reaches the button i want it to move left,because half the text gets cut off,i know overflow is hidden but if thats removed it would just write on top of the button.sorry to bother you

Comment: yeah i also want the btn user to grow,and i want the userdetails to only grow once it reaches the button,am i making sense?

Comment: i could be seen wrong,but the text still gets hidden behind the button,im trying to push it when it reaches the button,not go behind it

Comment: You know.. I think you should study the most common CSS properties and try to understand how they work together. I suspect that even if I provide you with a solution that may seem perfect now, as soon as you add another BtnUser you'll run into a bunch of issues (like using `id` instead of `class` and the fact that the logout button is placed inside the first BtnUser). You also have unnecessary wrappers: Why both User and BtnUser, or logoutDiv and BtnLogout? I'll update it one more time, but you don't seem to have only one issue here..